# Find Javascript Value Within String Where String Contains key/value

Tags: javascript, regex, indexof

I have a string that contains a number of parameter/value pairs in the form:

```
{type1|value1}{type2|value2} .....
```

I need to find if a specific type is within the string (currently using indexOf searching for `"{type3|"` for example) but then I need to retrieve the value from that pair.

I could just place the string from the start point into another string, then search for the location of the start and end of the value `("|" and "}")`, but I am sure there ought to be a simpler way, probably using Regex.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Yup, regex, seems like a good solution.

Comment: In case you were wondering why I needed this, I use this format to store multiple values in a single cookie. It works nicely and it's simpler than having to manage lots of cookies for a single program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='{type1|value1}{type2|value2}{type3|value3}{foo|bar}'
search='type3';
m = s.match(new RegExp('\\{' + search + '\\|([^}]+)'));

if (m)
   val=m[1]; //=> "value3"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var my_string = "{type1|value1}{type2|value2}";
var regEx = /\{(.*?)\}/g,
    match, object = {};

while ((match = regEx.exec(my_string)) !== null) {
    var key_value = match[1].split("|");
    object[key_value[0]] = key_value[1];
}

console.log(object);
# { type1: 'value1', type2: 'value2' }
```

Convert the string to an object like this. Now, lookups are trivial and faster.